# How to parse ambiguous characters with BioPython

Tags: python, parsing, sequence, biopython

I'm new to Python and to programming in general. I've installed BioPython in hopes that some of its components can help with a script that I'm working on. That script needs to handle many xread files, which each contain a matrix that I need to slice in several ways. I'm hoping that there already exists a sequence datatype or class (is there a difference?) that allows indexing in the odd ways required by sequences with ambiguous characters coded in formats other than IUPAC. For example, in the sequence.

```
2-123[01]3-22
```

The characters in the string literal `[01]` represent a single ambiguous character, either `0` or `1`, in the DNA sequence represented. So the slice `[-6:]` should return `3[01]3-22`. I haven't been able to find anything on this in the BioPython documentation, though I may have overlooked it. If there is something in BioPython that will do this, could you please point me toward the relevant documentation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a BioPython expert, but you could define your own class to work the way you need. You'll need to parse it first, perhaps using [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html). For example:

```py
import re
class Sequence(list):
    def __init__(self, s):
        if isinstance(s, str):
            self.extend(re.findall(r'[^\[\]]|\[\d+\]', s))
        else:
            list.__init__(self, s)
    def __str__(self):
        return ''.join(self)
    def __getslice__(self, i, j):
        l = list(self)
        return Sequence(l[i:j])
```

Testing it:

```py
In [1]: seq = Sequence('2-123[01]3-22')
```

It's a list inside...

```py
In [2]: seq
Out[2]: ['2', '-', '1', '2', '3', '[01]', '3', '-', '2', '2']
```

But behaves like a string!

```py
In [3]: print seq
2-123[01]3-22
In [4]: print seq[-6:]
3[01]3-22
```

Maybe you'll need to define some other [methods](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) to get the desired behavior.

Comment: This looks very promising. It'll take me a while to work with it, but I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: @pyrogerg Of course if BioPython implements it, that would be easier for you as a beginner. But this answer is intended to show how it can be done. Feel free to ask.